# StructureMap XML Configuration

Tags: structuremap

I'm trying to figure out how to define the following StructureMap DSL in my web.config:

```
For(typeof(ILog<>)).HttpContextScoped().Use(typeof(LogFactoryWrapper<>));
```

Does the XML approach even support this more unusual type of declaration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

> `<DefaultInstance PluginType="path.to.interface.ILog,assembly.withoutdll" PluggedType="path.to.implementation.Log,assembly.withoutdll" Scope="HttpContext" />`

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Dmiller (the father of StructureMap) wrote in his [blog](http://jeremydmiller.com/2012/01/11/kicking-off-structuremap-3/#comment-3650):

> As for the Xml configuration, it was going to be a near rewrite of the Xml configuration for StructureMap 3.0 and there wasn’t much demand for it. I’m happily open to pull requests if you want it for StructureMap 3.0, but it’s definitely going to be moved to a separate Nuget package because Xml support is not part of PCL.